# how to make image classification model to detect object and track object in a video

Tags: keras, tensorflow, image-classification, object-detection, opencv

i have built a disaster classification  model . now i want to use this classification model to detect ex- cyclone in a video to draw bounding box around it and track the cyclone if possible.is it possible to do so and how can i do that ? i am new to object detection so sorry if it doesn't make any sense.

[image]

this is what i have done so far, now i want to draw bounding box around the cyclone and also track the cyclone if possible.

Comment: so what is the problem with object-detection techniques? where you provide enough samples of object and let algorithm learn and use learned algorithm to track object in each video frame (and also add bounding box). For example openCV can be used with HAAR classifiers

Comment: yeah but i want to know is there any other way to get single object localization with the help of classification model. i could have tried other object detection techniques but i dont have enough time implement them(project submission due time)  .